# C# String from Constructor not passing to Form

Tags: c#, forms, constructor, pipe, program-entry-point

So i have written this tool that receives strings through a named pipe from another process. I want to pass the string that i receive from my main method to one of my forms but whenever i try it with a string constructor it seems like the values are empty.

I have a feeling that i did something wrong with the constructor or that the string isn't received from my currently running form...

Here my method for catching and sending the string in the main class:

```
public static async void startServer()
{

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipeToProgram"))
            {
                pipeStream.WaitForConnection();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
                {
                    string message;
                    while ((message = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Form1 form = new Form1(message); //passing the string
                    }
                    startServer(); //restarts server after passing string
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Here my constructor in Form1:

```
public Form1(string str)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessageBox.Show(str); //message arrives
    addToList(str);
}
```

Here my addToList method:

```
    public void addToList(string str)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(str); //arrives
        textBox1.Text = str; //not arriving/showing in form
    }
```

My main method:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (m.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
    {
        startServer();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());


    }
    else
    {
        startClient("message");
    }

}
```

Default constructor of Form1:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 1;
    Timer_start();
    checkWindowTimer_start();
    checkBox1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Is it because of the re-initializing of the components? But when i don't provide the InitializeComponents the tool won't start anymore

This feels to be something very simple but im struggling with this for quite a while now and i would greatly appreciate help from you guys :)

Thanks in advance
Ravand

Comment: Your posted code is pretty vague. It doesn't even show how you are showing the form after it's created. But: make sure you are creating and showing the form on an STA thread, and of course that you are in fact showing the form.

Comment: I have edited the first post, is that what u think was missing to clarify it a bit more? I am creating the Form on an STA thread

Comment: @RadioSpace thats what i want the list to show just for debugging purposes atm, but it's not showing it unfortunately on the actual listview

Comment: the list in particular is not my problem, even when i try to set a simple textbox text it won't show in my form.. EDIT: I have edited the first post to remove that misunderstanding

Comment: so even after you hit okay on the MessageBox the textbox doesn't change? even with a constant string it doesn't change?

Comment: @RadioSpace Yes exactly, when the startServer method is trying to send that message to method "addToList" in Form1 it is getting shown as a message box but it never arrives in the Form1 itself no matter if a textbox or listview or whatever. It seems like it is sending it to a wrong instance of form, because when i call the "addToList" method inside the Form1 class it works perfectly fine, it just doesn't work from the main class

Comment: @Ravand changing the UI from multithreaded application can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

when editing the UI from a multithreaded application you will likely need to use `Invoke`. you can only edit the UI from the thread it was started on

take this example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Random rand = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(changetextfromanotherthread);

    }

    void changetextfromanotherthread()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            Invoke((Action)(() => { textBox1.Text = "" + rand.Next(); }));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
        }

    }
}
```

this will successfully change the textbox 100 times from another thread.

if we remove invoke we will get and invalid operation exception when x == 1`. which states you cannot change the UI from another thread.

But you don't get that error do you

second remove the call to `Sleep(250)`. now the textbox gets changed once and no error. (I really have no idea why) which is similar to your problem.

anyways even if some of my points aren't valid for this context, change the textbox from inside Invoke.

Comment: Huh.. Ye you might be right it makes sense that i can't change the UI from a different thread... and yes you are right i don't get that exception, if i would have gotten it it would have helped alot actually... i will test this and reply if it worked. I still have a question though related to the Invoke: Do i have to Invoke from my startServer() method or can i simply do that in the addToList() method?

Comment: @Ravand I saw the Task at first but was more focused on the usage of listview which was poor observation on my part. I am glad you took that out.

Comment: i have to appologize i didn't remove those debugging lines before i posted it, which lead to this misunderstanding